# Cleaning an older swift application project using storyboards

Tags: swift, storyboard, iboutlet, ibaction, code-cleanup

I have been assigned a "new" old app project from my company, where there is a mix of older swift code and newer swift code. I am slowly getting comfortable with deleting and refactoring parts of the code, trying to remove the Xcode warnings and making the code safer in general... But since I am new to swift (especially storyboards), I am not sure when an @IBOutlet or @IBAction can be removed.

I have some @IBOutlets and @IBActions, where there are no 'dots' next to them:
[the circles to the left-side of the outlets don't have a dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cTjv.png)

Does this mean it is safe to change these from outlets to "regular" views? and is this also true for @IBActions?

Is this simply straight forward, no dot = No @IBOutlet/@IBAction needed?
Or is it trial and error: Try and remove, build & run, see if broken, redo...?
Or are there smarter ways to check these things?

Comment: There is no straightforward answer to this. The dot usually represents a connection with a storyboard. But in some scenarios it doesn't look connected but the storyboard depends on it.. I suggest you try some basic UiKit tutorials so you understand what is going on. Why do you think "regular"  views (whatever that means) are "better" than storyboards? It sounds like you are pretty new to swift. What is the point of removing the outlets and actions?

Comment: my suggestion (and I have a lot of experience refactoring old code): don't touch UI components, until you are ready to refactor them (e.g. move to SwiftUI, or just refresh the screen). It's not worth it. Changes are obscure (since the involve not only Swift code, but XML-based storyboard), it's time-consuming and error prone (unless you have an amazing set of UI tests - I am yet to see that). Instead, take screen by screen, move it to Swift UI, and in the process you will remove old stuff.

Comment: @loremipsum. The point was simply to find out how much of the code that storyboards depend on. In my mind, it was to clean the code, but also because I am much better at setting the layout programmatically. I have removed an "unused" view, but that left me with constraint issues in a storyboard and one little fix in there took me a lot of time.

Comment: @khjfquantumjj Thanks for the advice! Yes I will be looking forward to the time when we take the leap forward into SwiftUI.

Comment: It’s just busy work… unless you know the app really really well or have fantastic ui tests you will more than likely end up with an app full of issues.

Comment: @loremipsum Yeah. That seems to be an undeniable truth when working with storyboards. Thanks for your replies.